# Why does nginx (or php) turn spaces into underscores?

Tags: php, nginx

I have Nginx setup with a try_files statement:

```
location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @php;
}
location @php {
     rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?$1 last;
}
```

So `www.example.com/thisfolder` is handled by my index.php with a `$_GET['thisfolder']`, upon which PHP can act. This works fine.
However, the path in the URL can contain spaces like so: `www.example.com/this folder`.
In that case I get a `$_GET['this_folder']` (with an underscore), instead of the `$_GET['this folder']` that I expected.
Encoding the URL as `www.example.com/this%20folder` does not change anything. Is the space-to-underscore-replacement done by PHP or by Nginx and how do I get rid of it so PHP gets the parameter with a space in the name?

Comment: That's how `$_GET` parsing works in PHP. You can find the original URL query at `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.

Comment: Using that built-in variable works like a charm, thanks!